Switching a 9A 60VDC continous resistive load. P-Channel or Relay?
I need to add something on my PCB to drive a resistive load (Heater) from a battery stack which ranges from 20VDC-60VDC. The heater is 150W and so will be 2.5A-7.5A continous current draw as a worst case.
I was ideally looking at a relay but it seems that most are more suited to AC and stop around 32VDC. Other than a relay my other options I am looking at is potentially a standard N-channel mixed with a P-channel MOSFET setup to switch this ON from an IC digital output. I would use a standard HS switch but they seems to mostly be rated for 60V so not much headroom at all:

I could also put a N-channel on the GND line rather than anything on the power line I guess? Just means VGS will only be 5V.
Does it look like I have any other cost effective options? Which of these solutions would you go for?
thanks in advance!

A logic level MOSFET with a Rds(on) of <5mΩ shouldn't be too hard to find and, in a TO-220 package, should stay <20C above ambient without additional heatsinking (though it wouldn't hurt), which I would call reasonable. I would move R122 to the other side of R121 to eliminate the voltage divider effect and give yourself as much Vgs as possible.

Sorry do you mean a logic level N-channel and use that on the GND/Neg supply of the heater and keep postive side permanently connected? If so, the closest I can find is
IPD60N10S4L-12 which will be just under 15mohms so a low internal Pd.
I assume for overal idal Pd you need to add the load power (150W) to the MOSFET internal power due to current x RDSon?
Thanks for the support!

Are you switching the heater on and off or trying to adjust its power?

Just ON/OFF. The PTC heater is self limiting

N-channel on the low side is what I'd do but 15mΩ would give you ~52C junction temp rise above ambient which is getting into burn hazard territory. Power dissipation in the MOSFET is I²R where I is the load current and R is the Rds(on) at Vgs = 5V. 62C/W is standard temp rise for TO-220 in free air.

Ah ok, understood. So what is the Pd rating of the MOSFET for? Is that the power flowing through it rather than junction power due to resistnace?
If so, then maybe something like SQJ402EP-T1_GE3 will be better (As part cost is lower) and just use 2 in parallel instead which will be ~13degC rise on each at 5V. Realistically I should not see above 6A as I will probably turn the heater off as cells hit 3V rather than 2.8V per cell which would be the 7.5A value
This will also only ever be active at below 20degC.

Actually a single SQJQ410EL-T1_GE3 might be the one to work on it's own. 136W Pd ~4mohm RDSon at 5V. The only question is whether the 150W heater has any impact on the MOSFET Pd? Thanks again!

The power dissipation number for the MOSFET is how much power it can dissipate inside itself from Id*Rds losses (mostly) before it burns up. At 4mΩ and 7.5A you will be dissipating 0.225W. The 136W is kind of a marketing number that assumes you have some way of keeping the junction at 25C. At that power level you would probably need liquid nitrogen cooling; I doubt even a chilled water setup could remove heat quickly enough.

Ah that makes more sense then! Ok so, a single SQJQ410EL-T1_GE3 sounds like it will work with the worst case 0.225W this should be ok for continous use. I will also have 4 layers of copper I can stitch it to for extra heat dissipation. Does this sounds realistic? So my driveing circuit will be Pos permanently supplied and the GND will be switch with this circuit to turn the heater ON:
https://imgur.com/a/01qimkG

TO-220 dissipates heat out of the tab so a cheap screw-on heatsink is what you would want, but it's unnecessary at these power levels. Note that the tab is usually not electrically isolated. If you want to use a SMD package, then you need to do board area calculations for your heatsink copper pour, but that's a whole other ball of wax.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
